# how to add Sweet Alert in firebase connection?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, sweetalert

I'm trying to add a SweetAlert when contact form successfully but no idea about how to add sweet alert message within firebase angular connection.

contact-service.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import swal from 'sweetalert';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactServiceService {

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

  /* Add Document */
  AddDocument(document: Document) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.firestore.collection("contact").add(document)
        .then(res => {
          resolve(res);
        }, err => reject(err));
    });
  }
}
```

contact.component.ts

please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

swal() returns promise so you can chain it with firebase call

is this work for you?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import swal from 'sweetalert';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactServiceService {

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

  /* Add Document */
  AddDocument(document: Document) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.firestore.collection("contact").add(document)
        .then(res => {

          return swal('success').then(() => {
            resolve(res);
          });

        }, err => reject(err));
    });
  }
}
```